# Make default constructor templated to avoid early-template-instantiation bug in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates

I have a class that takes care of some helpful tasks with various types and ACTS like that type. The import part is that the class looks like this:

```
template <typename Super>
class Wrapper : public Super
{
public:
    Wrapper ()
    :   Super ()
        { }

    template <typename Arg1>
    Wrapper ( Arg1 const & arg1 )
    :   Super ( arg1 )
        { }

    // More like that...
} ;
```

The idea is that if you would ordinarily call:

```
MyClass1 * pObject1 = new MyClass1 ( "My String" ) ;
MyClass2 * pObject2 = new MyClass2 () ;
```

You could instead call:

```
MyClass1 * pObject1 = new Wrapper<MyClass1> ( "My String" ) ;
MyClass2 * pObject2 = new Wrapper<MyClass2> () ;
```

(Note: please don't question the need to do this. There is a need.)

Sometimes, Super will have a default constructor. Sometimes it won't. But the Wrapper class is always the same.

The problem: Visual Studio 2010 appears to have an early-template-instantiation bug and instantiates the default-constructor when the class is instantiated (even when it's not called!) and causes either a permissions-error or a no-method-found-error (depending on the Super).

This issue doesn't happen with the templated constructors because they DEFINITELY aren't instantiated until they're used. So, I'd like to use this to fix the default constructor.

Note that all this code works perfectly in GCC 4.2, GCC 4.1, and LLVM 4.2.1. I even have cmake generate the makefiles, X-Code project files and VS2010 project files from the same CMakeLists file: the EXACT same code (except minor low-level abstraction stuff that doesn't use these classes) is used for both.

One thing I tried (unsuccessfully):

```
template <typename Super>
class Wrapper : public Super
{
public:
    struct DummyStruct { } ;

    template <typename Arg1>
    Wrapper ( Arg1=int() , DummyStruct=DummyStruct() )
    :   Super ()
        { }

    template <typename Arg1>
    Wrapper ( Arg1 const & arg1 )
    :   Super ( arg1 )
        { }

    // More like that...
} ;
```

VS2010 complains that no default constructor is found in Wrapper, though it doesn't tell me in what context it's being called.

Any suggestions on how to force the default constructor in the Wrapper to be on-demand only (like, by the standards, it should be) would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Update/More Details (2012 Dec 8 10.22 MST):

The particular case VS complains about is this:

```
class MyGenericSuper
{
public:
    MyGenericSuper ( std::string const & inOnlyArgument )
        { }
} ;

class MyClass : Wrapper<MyGenericSuper>
{
public:
    MyClass ( std::string const & inOnlyArgument )
    :   Wrapper<MyGenericSuper> ( inOnlyArgument )
        { }
} ;
```

EVERY subclass of MyGenericSuper has the exact same constructor and passes its argument to the super. Also, they're only ever instantiated from an abstract factory, so I'm guaranteed to only be creating them using that one argument (because only the factory creates it).

In addition, there's only ONE class that uses Wrapper (which appears to be the location of the error) and it doesn't have a default constructor to call its super...

Comment: Do you have a link that confirms this bug you refer to? Because the symptoms you're describing sound like [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) effects.

Comment: @WhozCraig this seems consistent with the VS incorrectly implemented two-phase lookup mess.

Comment: @juanchopanza *love* those guys =P

Comment: It's strange to hear of an "early instantiation bug" with MSVC, since the "two-phase lookup mess" that @juanchopanza was referring to is that they don't implement the first phase *at all* except for basic syntax checking. Anyways, in VC10 you're screwed since they don't implement function template default arguments, which would allow `template<class T = int> Wrapper(T const& v = T()) : Super(){}`.

Comment: @Xeo, yeah, I tried that too...

Comment: You've probably moved on from this question since it's been over six months, but I came across it and found it interesting. I tried to reproduce the problem with your `Wrapper` class in a couple scenarios similar to those described. I did not see the error you referenced. My last attempt is at http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/Dme (I know rise4fun uses VS2012, but I saw the same results in VS2010). Seems there's more going on, would you mind elaborating more? Do you have a short example that produces the error?

Comment: Not reproducible here too. (I wonder how this question got to the front page after almost a year).

Comment: @n.m. it was bumped to the front page due to [Łukasz L.'s trivial edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/13775406/5). Looks like he's going for the Archaeologist badge.